# What is the regex to replace every html tag that does not have a space behind them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I have a string that contains html tags, f.e hyperlinks, divs, etc. I would like to replace only the html tags that have a space behind them. My current regex does not do the job, since it also replaces html tags that have a space behind them:

```js
var string = "<p> Did you know that </p>#love is in the <span>air?</span>";
string= string.replace(/(<[^>]*>)/gm, "$1 ");
console.log(string);
```

The red rectangles below mark which html elements should be replaced in this text example. As you can see, the first paragraph element should not be included, because it has a space behind it already.

[image]

Please test my regex at: https://regex101.com/r/9FfbEp/2

Comment: `.replace(/<[^>]*>(?!\s)/g, "$& ")`, no need for a capturing group here and the modifier `m` is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead `(?!\s)` to avoid matching tag followed by space character

```js
var string = "<p> Did you know that </p>#love is in the <span>air?</span>";
let final = string.replace(/(<[^>]*>)(?!\s)/gm, "$1 ");
console.log(final);
```